# WordPress update failing

Tags: wordpress

I'm having a problem when trying to update WordPress to the latest version I get the following error:

**Download failed.: Destination directory for file streaming does not exist or is not writable.
Installation Failed**

I'm also having the same problem when uploading images, it fails and gives the following error

**has failed to upload due to an error
The uploaded file could not be moved to "the website path and then uploads directory"**

I have checked the permissions of the folders and the folders themselves are set to 755 & the files inside them set to 644.

Could anyone tell me why it would be doing this?

Where running a plesk server.

Thank You,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions you're using seem reasonable, but they will only work if the FTP user that WordPress is using (set in your wp_config.php file) is the same as the owner of those files/folders.

Answer (score 6):

Are there any more error messages, probably also in the servers log files? Probably the download for the update should be done to `/tmp` and you are not allowed to store files there? Try setting the constant `WP_TEMP_DIR` which should change the directory. Put something like this in your `wp_config.php`:

> define('WP_TEMP_DIR', ABSPATH . 'wp-content/');

Comment: Thank you for the reply I tried that and still the same, I checked the error logs on the server and am getting the following message repeatedly SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The script whose uid is 10001 is not allowed to access /tmp owned by uid 0 in /var/www/vhosts/siteurl/httpdocs/wp-admin/includes/file.php on line 509, referer: siteurl

Comment: That's what I mentioned: WP still tries to write into `/tmp`. Are you sure you added the upper line into wp_config.php?

Comment: Yeah I added it, ill try again now.

Comment: Tried again and still the same, I found turning off PHP Safe mode has fixed my updating problem. Just the images now that wont upload.

Comment: I had this exact same issue, and adding this line in wp_config.php fixed my problem. Thanks.

Comment: Due to the nature of IIS Hosting. I'm upgrading my PHP from 5.2 to 5.3 and received the same error. The first solution works well for me. This is the reason because of invalid hash/user ID that allowed to write in temp folder.

Comment: Under Windows, I added `define('WP_TEMP_DIR', ABSPATH . 'wp-content/temp');` and gave Network Service (under which the app pool is running) Read-Write permissions.