# WordPress update error

Tags: wordpress, permissions

When I try update WordPress to the latest version I get the following error:

"Download failed.: Destination directory for file streaming does not exist or is not   writable. Installation Failed"

We are running WordPress on a dedicated Win 2008 R2 server in IIS 7.5
Could you help me to fix this error or at least help me to find out under which account WordPress tries to access the filesystem?
None of the suggestions in the similar question ([WordPress update failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725157/wordpress-update-failing)) work. Nor have I found anything that works on WordPress support site.

Comment: please move to wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the PHP user has permissions to the WordPress directory.
This is confusing for IIS to determine the actual user.

Typically, it is **IUSR**, not the application pool identity user.